# PHP while loop array to JavaScript infinitely looping

Tags: javascript, php, loops, while-loop

Why this is sending an infinite loop to my JavaScript function, rather than just sending the 1 clicked result as my other while loop does?

Here are the 2 codes, the 1st the problematic, that loops over n over again, and throws a `NAN` after so long, `n` then breaks... The second the same while loop from MySQL database with same `onclick` event same retrieval of variables and same function, but the 1st problematic while loop just loops infinitely instead of sending the 1 value...

1st code...

```
echo "<div class='pagebuttonsdiv'>";
        while($x < $pagesnum) {
           $x++;    
           $xpage = $x*9;
           echo "<div class='pagebuttons' onclick='pageclick({$xpage},{$display},{$maxresults},{$startfrom});'>
             {$x}</div>";
           if ($x>$display) {
              echo"<br>"; };
           if ($x >$pagesnum) {
              $x=0; }     
        };
echo "</div>";
```

2nd code

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    <video id='$vidd' title='{$row['title']} {$row['locate']}' style='position:absolute; left:0px; top:18%; width:100%; height:60%; transform: scale(1.0,1.1);' preload='metadata' controls='controls'>
        <source src='vid/{$row['videos']}.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
        <source src='vid/{$row['videos']}.mp4' type='video/ogg'>
        <source src='vid/{$row['videos']}.mp4' type='video/webm'>                
    </video >

    <div id='vidicon' title='Video's' class='vidicon' onclick='controlshowvid($vidd , $pidd);' >
    "; 
}
```

Comment: `if ($x >$pagesnum) {$x=0;}` is most likely being triggered which means the end of this clause `while($x < $pagesnum)` is never met

Comment: Iv been meddling with that relation with many differnt, i used 0 to see if it would return true immediatly, but it still loops infintly regardless of what association. i have it assigned to $pagenum which=9 in my code, but it bypasses 9 totally and goes way past it to NAN regardless. iv tried == ect also, to no avail. the loop just loops over n over until it NAN's which is for True i would image. but why the while loop continues is baffling. as i say the same code in code 2 does the exact same thing, only difference is false is decleared because of mysql $data being !empty or null..

Comment: I don't see any Javascript loops, just a PHP loop.

Comment: I don't think `$x > $pagesnum` can ever be true. On the last iteration of the `while` loop, `$x == $pagesnum-1`. Then it does `$x++`, so `$x == $pagesnum`.

Comment: Why are you using `.mp4` suffixes for `ogg` and `webm` videos?

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code correctly here? You would have an infinite loop if you write `while ($x <= $pagesnum)` or `if ($x >= $pagesnum)`.

Answer (score 0):

What is the condition you are looking for with x? X should not equal page num?

First thing that happens in the loop, x is incremented.
When the code reaches the mentioned if statement, if x is greater than pagenum the code in that if block resets x to 0 and it goes on back to the start of the loop.

Perhaps there is no reason for that if statement.

Also with the code here x doesn't seem to be modified other than the increment and should reach the condition to exit the loop eventually.

When you say NaN, I believe there is something wrong in the JavaScript code as well.

Comment: If we start with `$x = $pagesnum`, we'll never go into the loop because `while ($x < $pagesnum)` will be false.

Comment: i have page numbers from 1 -(9) - so 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 . with an onclick=('sendto foo ({$x}) ');  -> jscript receives the clicked page number, which it does initially... (what number i clik is the 1st number recieved But rather than it receive the Single number, it loops over and over upto NAN as php($true) - in the function i am x = x*9 - which it cannot parse as ($true)=NAN . but what is annoying me is the fact that its looping through the numbers, rather than just sending the clicked number, as my other  CODE2 does...

Comment: I need toi find another way around it i guess...But why it sends the whole array is what i cant understand. it should only send the clicked number...

Comment: echo"
     <div class='pagebuttonsdiv'>
   ";
   while($x < $pagesnum) {$x++;    
 if ($x > $pagesnum) {$x==$pagesnum;}
   echo "<div class='pagebuttons' onclick='pageclick({$x},{$display}, {$maxresults} , {$startfrom});'>
      {$x}</div>";

Comment: echo"
     <div class='pagebuttonsdiv'>
   ";

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo "<div class='pagebuttons' onclick='pageclick({$row},{$display}, {$maxresults} , {$startfrom});'>
      {$x}</div>";
  
        WORKS

Comment: function pageclick(pagex , display , maxresults , startfrom){
alert([pagex] )

document.getElementById('startpoint').value = pageclick(startfrom); return false;
document.getElementById('pagechange').submit(); return false; 
}

</script>

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

 echo"
     <div class='pagebuttonsdiv'>
      ";
 for ( $x =1 ; $x < $pagesnum ; $x++ ) {   
 if ($x > $pagesnum) {$x==$pagesnum;}
   echo "<div class='pagebuttons' onclick='pageclick({$x},{$display}, {$maxresults} , {$startfrom});'>
      {$x}</div>";



      };

echo"

?>

<script>

function pageclick(pagex , display , maxresults , startfrom){
alert([pagex])

var startfrom=pagex*9

ERROR --->document.getElementById('startpoint').value = >removed ERROR(pageclick) (startfrom);<<<=

NOW --->document.getElementById('startpoint').value = (startfrom);

document.getElementById('pagechange').submit(); return false;   
}

</script>
```

It now POST's the single value, Reason it was looping, was because it couldn't POST.

Answer (score 0):

have you try to intval($pagenum), i am curious as what is the data type being used.

or you can try to set the value for those 2 variables on top of your while loop.
$x=0;
$pagenum=9;

Answer (score 0):

This is why you get an infinity loop:

```
echo "<div class='pagebuttonsdiv'>";
        while($x < $pagesnum) { // x < pagesnum -> enters the lopp, so it get out of the loop on x >= pagesnum
           $x++;    
           $xpage = $x*9;
           echo "<div class='pagebuttons' onclick='pageclick({$xpage},{$display},{$maxresults},{$startfrom});'>
             {$x}</div>";
           if ($x>$display) {
              echo"<br>"; };
           if ($x >$pagesnum) {
              $x=0; }     // when it's supposed to get out the loop you put it 0 (zero) so unless pagesnum is zero or less it will loop forever
        };
echo "</div>";
```